# non www to www using AWS Elastic Load balancer and Nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, http-redirect

I have an app running on example.com and now I wanna redirect all the traffic to the www.example.com since we are collaborating with Akamai's CDN for your website. My domain is parked in Route53, added the CNAME of Elastic Load Balancer's CNAME to pointing to *.example.com and I am running nginx web server with the following configuration. If I use this configuration ELB is throwing the instance out, now domain.com works fine and www.domain.com fine, but redirecting is not happening.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
#       rewrite ^    http://www.example.com$request_uri? permanent;
        root /home/ubuntu/apps/st/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
}
```

but I am not able to achieve the redirect.

Also tried to add the PTR whose value is the cname of the load balancer.

Tried to change the nginx configuration, as you can see

`rewrite ^    http://www.example.com$request_uri? permanent`;

even that is not working.

As soon as I add the above line, the app instance goes and ELB throws out of the stack.

What is the solution, I have been trying to achieve this since 3-4 days, its become a night mare now, kindly help me up. I have also put posts and threads in aws forums, nothing is helping as such.

Comment: The ELB isn't really a variable here. It just blindly forwards HTTP requests to the instances. Hostnames don't matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue with the redirect (using same nginx conf code as shown here).

Then, I put my redirect configs as the last server{} block (at the end of my domain.com config file), and the ELB was able to find the instances again.

I have not looked more into it, but it seems that vhost processing is done in order, so when ELB hits the IP address of my servers, it lands on the first defined server{} block, which in my case was the redirect. Nginx throws a 301 return code, and ELB freaks out since its not 200.

Just a guess though.

So, my config (real vhost on top, redirect is last):

> less /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    .....
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain.com;
    return       301 http://domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Amazon ELB, but perhaps I can help with the nginx part.

For your scenario, I normally use two server blocks in nginx.  One to handle the rewrite/ redirect (example.com), and the other to handle the regular site (www.example.com). Both blocks can be in the same file.

```
# for redirecting only...
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    # re-written to www...
    location / {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.example.com$1 permanent;
    }
}

# regular web site config here...
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    root /home/ubuntu/apps/st/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    ...
}
```

Comment: chue x , i tried the changes you added here , but its not worked , when i hit the url , it shows , webpage not found . am i missed any other changes need to be done along with above changes .

Comment: @ManjunathBavihal - did you restart nginx after you made the changes? Regarding the error message, is there any mention of nginx? I assume that the browser shows the non www url address?

Comment: @chuex if I rewrite or redirect in nginx ELB is throwing that instance out of the ELB and makes it in accessible

Comment: @JeevanDongre - I am afraid I don't know ELB at all. The above configuration is very a simple nginx configuration, and does work for my web sites.

Comment: @JeevanDongre - just one thought. Does the ELB ping your site based on address? In other words does it make a request to either `example.com` or `www.example.com`? If it is trying to go to the first, you should instead configure it to go the second. (The first will always return http 301, the second will return 200). This may be why your web server is getting pulled out of the cluster.

Comment: I am now I am able to ping both thats example.com and also www.example.com but I need to redirect to www.example.com from  just example.com. Thats not happening.

Comment: @chuex If I use the above configuration ELB throws out the instance from its stack, so I had to remove it, I tried to manipulate Route53 even thats not helping.

Comment: @JeevanDongre - If you are using ELB to ping both domains, then that could be your problem. Like I said, ELB should only ping the domain with `www`.

Comment: How do I make sure that ELB to ping only www.domain.com, any heads up?

Comment: @JeevanDongre - sorry, no idea on that. I am guessing that the reason it fails is because nginx always returns a 301 from the first domain. This is needed for any browser to redirect. If ELB must ping the first domain, then you will have to set up an nginx handler specifically for ELB. Maybe set up a server block on nginx to listen on port 81 and to always return 200. Then your ELB can ping that port and get what it is expecting (200).

Comment: @JeevanDongre - the downside, when using my workaround above, is that ELB will only be testing to see if nginx is running. You won't be able to make sure that your actual website is running. The best way is to have ELB ping the `www` site.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot @chuex, I will try it out tomorrow morning. thank you very much

Comment: @chuex I changed route53 configuration to point the ELB A record to point to www.domain.com but after using the configuration ELB throws out the instance again.

Comment: @JeevanDongre - Sorry, I am out of ideas on this. You might want to talk to amazon support. They will have a better idea as to why ELB is doing this. At the very least, they can help debug the problem for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but since it comes up in searches.

Redirecting to www (or any other host) is now possible with AWS application load balancers. This could be more convenient to manage than using nginx config.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html