# AWS : Classic Load Balancer www.example.com not redirecting to https://www.example.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess

I have an EC2 instance on AWS which has route53 hosted zone.I have used AWS Certificate Manager for SSL and then used Classic Load balancer for the same to achieve https redirection.

I have simple website running on that instance and have apache server installed with it. Also I have made .htaccess file for redirection.

It works on following cases:

```
1] example.com -> https://www.example.com
2] https://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
3] http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
```

It should also work on the following case but it does not

```
www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
```

I have written all the htaccess rule perfectly but when I add www redirection rule the load balancer status goes OutService.When I remove that rule it works perfectly.

Working .htaccess for normal cases

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I add rule for    www.example.com -> https://www.example.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Can you show me the status message of that OutService load balancer?

Comment: yes sure I will attach it

Comment: Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively. - Out of service

Comment: Have you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847888/non-www-to-www-using-aws-elastic-load-balancer-and-nginx

Comment: Yes but I am not using Nginx

Comment: What is the health check port of your classic load balancer? Is it 200? if so, try changing it to 8080. and, also allow port 8080 in ec2 and load balancer security group.

Comment: It is port 80 in load balancer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because your classic ELB health check is set on HTTP and it expects 200 okay reply from server but because of redirection rules, it's getting 302/301.
One solution would be to use TCP for health check, it'll only check SYN, SYN+ACK, however, the more robust solution is to use Application load balancer, you can choose your own success Health check Status code (2xx,3xx) and you don't need redirection rule on backend, ALB provides redirection rules which you can use for all of above purpose.

Comment: James Dean, I have removed my instance from classic to application load balancer. now how am i supposed to bind current instance to application load balancer?

Comment: You need to create a Target group and add your instance to it, the Target group will be added to the Load balancer. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html

Comment: I have tried the same and happend the same problem while writting rule for
www.example.com -> https://www.example.com.

It returns 301 health check and when i remove that rule it returns 200

Comment: I have resolved the issue by changing the htaccess rule. So the problem was for only healthcheck and to resolve that we need to bypass healthcheck rule.

Comment: @chirag It's good that you resolved the issue and create a bypass health check path but if something wrong with the app and health check is still passing, you'll see problems in the future.

Comment: you are right i will try my best to resolve that issue permanently. Thanks for your guidance